# Recursive function to find the number of ways a number can be generated out of a set of numbers

Tags: php, recursion

I had a job interview test and the question I got was about making a function which would return the number of ways a number could be generated by using numbers from a certain set and any number in the set can be used N times.

It is like if I have the number 10 and I want to find out how many ways **10** can be generated using [**2,3,5**]

1. 2+2+2+2+2 = 10
2. 5+3+2 = 10
3. 2+2+3+3 = 10
4. 5+5 = 10

to solve it I made this function:

```
function getNumberOfWays($money, $coins) {
    static $level = 0;
    if (!$level) {
        sort($coins);
    }

    if ($level && !$money) {
        return 1;
    } elseif (!$level && !$money) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($money === 1 && array_search(1, $coins) !== false) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($money === 1 && array_search(1, $coins) === false) {
        return 0;
    }

    $r = 0;
    $tmpCoins = $coins;
    foreach ($coins as $index => $coin) {
        if (!$coin || $coin > $money) {
            continue;
        }

        $tmpCoins[$index] = 0;
        $tmpMoney = $money;
        do {
            $tmpMoney -= $coin;
            if ($tmpMoney >= 0) {
                $level++;
                $r += getNumberOfWays($tmpMoney, $tmpCoins);
                $level--;
            } elseif (!$tmpMoney) {
                $r++;
            }
        } while ($tmpMoney >= 0);
    }

    return $r;
}
```

This function works ok and returns the right value.
My question is if there is a better way for it.

Thanks

Comment: This question might be better asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks

Comment: I recommend looking into memoization/caching/dynamic programming to store results you've already computed. I'd also use a function wrapper for "level 0" setup tasks so that you can eliminate all those checks and extra variables in the recursion. Ultimately, your function should not time out for https://projecteuler.net/problem=31

Comment: Also, on my last comment, I missed the restriction of only using a number `n` times. How is your code handling that--what is `n`?

Comment: @ggorlen By `n` I mean that any number in the set can be used as many times as needed. :)